# CSS For Variable Height Footer that Floats to Bottom of Page (Not Viewport)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, footer

I'm working on a React app and trying to create a footer that floats to the bottom of the page (not viewport) if there is not enough content to fill the space. Also, the footer height will vary as the browser hits media breakpoints.

Here's a high-level overview of the html:

```
<div id="root">
  <div data-reactroot id="app">
    <div id="modal">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="header">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="container">
      ...
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-bottom bg-faded">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/terms-of-use">Terms of Service</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant CSS (note current css prevents page overscrolling - I removed my failed attempts to solve this issue):

```
#footer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
}

#root, #app {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Also, please note that I've found a gazillion similar questions about this issue on Stack, but literally none that stipulate a footer with a variable height AND a footer that isn't sticky (i.e. positioned at bottom of viewport).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, so going to repeat back my understanding.

1. You want the footer to always be below the rest of the content
2. If the page is less than the size of the viewport, you want the footer to be at the bottom of the viewport
3. If the page is greater than the size of the viewport, the footer should just be directly below the rest of the content.

Assuming this is the case, I think the simplest way to solve this is to set a min-height on your #app to be at least 100vh and use flexbox to expand the container to fill additional space if it exists.

Given your current HTML structure, this would look like:

```
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

You can see this in action here: https://codepen.io/kball/pen/YxmgBL

If my understanding of your question/desired outcome is incorrect, please let me know and I'll take another pass at it.

Comment: Your understanding is correct; also, apologies for the confusing description - I work primarily on the backend. Also, this solution is amazing. Thanks!